# How can I use MySQL spatial datatypes with linked data for polygons?

Tags: mysql, database, gis, spatial, redundancy

I will have a table with a lot of points (declared as POINT). Now I want to create another table with some polygons and similar. The polygons should be linked to the points of the first table; if I change one point in the first table, the polygons in the second table should updated automatically - they should be linked.

Is this possible? Or should I copy the data for myself and create the redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key for the points, and reference this column from the polygon table (foreign key reference). When you query the polygons you join the two tables.

EDIT

Previous solution is wrong, it's correct if you reference polygon id from points table like this:

```
Points (id, coordx, coordy, polygon_id, ...)
Polygons (id, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I see some problems: the polygons may have different number of points (not ideal for joins), and I want to use things like included-in-region-checks etc. Is this easily doable?